# Запрос к серверу:Get. Доступ к данным по ответу сервера

Tags: c++, qt, ооп, qt5, qtcreator

Я пишу класс на с++ в QT, который работает с API сервера. Одна из задач считать данные из базы данных сервера и преобразовать их к типу QVariantMap, а потом в QString  для записи в локальную базу данных.
Проблема с которой я столкнулся такова, что я не могу получить доступ к полю класса которое хранит в себе данные ответа сервера вне класса.

```
В api.cpp:
в конструкторе пишу коннект: 

    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(getReply(QNetworkReply*)));
    
    void API::readAllFromTable(const QString &tableName)
    {
        if(!tableNameError(tableName))
        {
            _tableName=tableName;
    
            QUrl url;
            url.setScheme("http");
            url.setHost(_host);
            url.setPath("/api/"+tableName+"/read.php");
    
            QNetworkRequest request;
            request.setUrl(url);
            manager->get(request);
        }
    }
    
    void API::getReply(QNetworkReply *reply)
    {
        reply -> waitForReadyRead(1000);
    
        jsonDocument = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll(),&jsonError);
    
        if(jsonError.errorString()=="no error occurred")
        {
            _replyData = jsonToVariantMap(jsonDocument);
            qDebug()<<"jsonDocument"<<jsonDocument;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug()<<"Error: "<<jsonError.errorString();
        }
        reply->deleteLater();
    }
    
    QVariantMap API::getReplyData()
    {
        return _replyData;
    }

В main.cpp:

    QVariantMap data;
    API api;
    api.readAllFromTable("client");
    data = api.getReplyData();
```

метод getReplyData возвращает null, поскольку слот getReply еще не успел отработать. Подскажите как мне решить эту проблему, я думаю над тем чтобы перед вызовом метода getReplyData установить таймер, но мне кажется что это неправильно.

Comment: Не используй передачу ответа напрямую - используй слоты.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то устраивать долгоиграющую обработку в основном потоке программы - дурной тон! И без разницы, Qt приложение с GUI или без. Основной поток программы предназначен для взаимодействием с пользователем и не более. В расчет не берем операции с данными, которые занимают микро/нано секунды.

А вот для продолжительной обработки данных следует открыть для себя "[Multithreaded Programming with Future & Promise](https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/04/18/multithreaded-programming-future-promise)". В сети об этом полно информации. Есть и другие средства распараллеливания обработки данных. Но основное правило, как писал выше - не упарываться с данными в основном потоке.

Для взаимодействие потоков вполне себе решение - механизм сигналов/слотов. Если данных чрезвычайно много, можно решить вопрос мьютексами и разделяемой памятью.

**Замечание по коду**

`reply -> waitForReadyRead(1000);` нужно не в слоте устанавливать, а до запуска `manager->get(request)`. Так как слот вызывается тогда, когда все данные уже получены.

**Набросал небольшой проект**

Не то, чтобы эталон - но работающий черновик, так сказать, по теме.

*AsyncReply.pro*

```
QT -= gui
QT += core network concurrent

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QThread>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QtConcurrent>
// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
class JsonWorker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    QString Url;
    QNetworkAccessManager M;
    QNetworkReply *Rep;
    QJsonDocument Json;
  public:
    JsonWorker(QString iUrl = ""): Url(iUrl) {}
    QJsonDocument Get() {
      QNetworkRequest Req(Url);
      Rep = M.get(Req);
      QEventLoop Loop;
      connect(Rep, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &JsonWorker::finish);
      connect(Rep, &QNetworkReply::errorOccurred, this, &JsonWorker::error);
      // ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
      // Прогресс закоментил, чтобы не засорять вывод
      // connect(Rep, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, this, &JsonWorker::progress);
      // ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
      connect(this, &JsonWorker::done, &Loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
      Loop.exec();
      return Json;
    }
  public slots:
    void finish() {
      Json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(Rep->readAll());
      emit done();
    }
    void error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError code) {
      std::cout << "Worker net error: " << code;
    }
    void progress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal) {
      std::cout << "Worker process: " << bytesReceived << "/" << bytesTotal;
    }
  signals:
    void done();
};
// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
class JsonReader : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    QFuture<QJsonDocument> read(const QString& iUrl) {
      auto lambdaJsonWorker = [&](const QString & iUrl) {
        JsonWorker Worker(iUrl);
        return Worker.Get();
      };
      return QtConcurrent::run(lambdaJsonWorker, iUrl);
    };
};
// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
class NetTask : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    QString Url;
    JsonReader Reader;
    QFuture<QJsonDocument> Future;
    NetTask(QObject *parent = 0, QString url = "") : QObject(parent), Url(url) {}
  public slots:
    void run() {
      QFutureWatcher<QJsonDocument> *Watcher =
        new QFutureWatcher<QJsonDocument>(this);
      Future = Reader.read(Url);
      Watcher->setFuture(Future);
      Watcher->waitForFinished();
      delete Watcher;
      emit ready();
    }
    void print() {
      QJsonDocument Json = Future.result();
      std::cout << Json.toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented).constData();
      emit done();
    }
  signals:
    void ready();
    void done();
};
// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#include "main.moc" // <--- так как Q_OBJECT залепил в самом "main.cpp"
// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  #ifdef QT_NO_CONCURRENT
#error "Ups!"
  #else
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  NetTask *task = new NetTask(&a, "http://testo/index.php");
  QObject::connect(task, &NetTask::ready, task, &NetTask::print);
  QObject::connect(task, &NetTask::done, &a, &QCoreApplication::quit);
  QTimer::singleShot(0, task, &NetTask::run);
  return a.exec();
  #endif
}
```

Comment: Принято, спасибо большое

Comment: спасибо за код, многое не понятно, есть пища для размышлений

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите выдавать ответ в той функции что вызвали, то нужно обрабатывать работу цикла qt в этой функции.

```
while(!done)
{
    QApplication::processEvents(); 
}
```

Но лучше проектировать приложение на работу со слотами. Выдавать ответ сигналом. Можно передавать функцию как замыкание (как в яваскрипте get(..., function(result) {... }))